# Facebook post created by php not visible to all visitors

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've a little script that create a new post on Facebook page where I am the admin.

I've create an app from developer.facebook.com with permission: manage_pages , publish_pages.

App-fb actually is in dev-mode.

My script to publish post on facebook works BUT i'm the only can view posts! And i see that publisher of the post is my app.

If I try to disconnect and enter on facebook page like a simple visitor....i can't see these posts!

If I switch app-fb in LIVE MODE, i get error permission. Where I wrong? can I stay in dev-mode or I need to go to live mode?

Comment: You need to go live - any content created via an app in dev mode, will only be visible to users with a role in the app. And you need to get the permissions your app uses reviewed by Facebook, before this will work.

Comment: @CBroe yes i request approvation by FB days ago... I see all checks are green but after i set ALIVE, i see yellow check that tell me i need more COMPANY CHECK.... i don't have a company...my script is for my personal page.... what I need to do?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#individual-verification